# grep and sed command

Tags: string, sed, grep, unique, extract

i have a truckload of files with sql commands in them, i have been asked to extract all database table names from the files
How can I use grep and sed to parse the files and create a list of the unique table names in a text file ..one per line?

the name names all seem to start with "db_" which is handy!

what would be the best way to use grep and sed together to pull the table names out?

Comment: Can you post an example of what the SQL files look like?

Comment: Almost any answer you get from sed/grep is mostly going to confirm your assumption going into it. I.e. if you start by searching for `db_`, that's exactly what you're going to get, regardless of how accurate it really is -- any strings that start that way will be shown, even if they aren't table names, and any strings that don't fit that pattern won't be shown, even if they do refer to tables. Unfortunately, a correct answer will require an (almost) complete SQL parser...

Answer (score 6):

This will search for lines containing the table names.  The output of this will quickly reveal if a more selective search is needed:

```
grep "\<db_[a-zA-Z0-9_]*" *.sql
```

Once the proper search is sorted out, remove all other characters from lines with tablenames:

```
grep "\<db_[a-zA-Z0-9_]*" *.sql  |  sed 's/.*\(\<db_[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\).*/\1/'
```

Once that's running, add on a sort and remove duplicates:

```
(same last pipe expression)  |  sort  |  uniq
```

Comment: +1. To catch potentially several table names in the same line, you can split the lines with tr: `grep .. *.sql | tr ' ' '\n' | grep .. | sed`. First grep is to ease the burden for `tr`, the second grep is to filter out the non-"db_" parts.

Answer (score 0):

you just need grep

```
grep -owE "db_[a-zA-Z0-9]+" file|sort -u
```

or awk

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^db_[a-zA-Z0-9]+/){print $i} }' file
```